# Self documenting typescript / javascript code

Tags: javascript, typescript

What approach / tools do you use to document typescript / javascript code?
For c# in visual studio, it's very simple. You just type "///" and the IDE automatically creates for you the documentation stub. But what about typescript? Any standards, tools, approaches?

P.S. I prefer the way of self-documenting would not depend on the IDE.

Comment: How about http://typedoc.io ?

Comment: @NitzanTomer thanks, actually I meant the standard of comments formatting but not the tool to generate the documentation. Nevertheless, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any standards, tools, approaches

TypeScript documentation follows the JavaScript documentation practice i.e. JSDoc : http://usejsdoc.org/

> I prefer the way of self-documenting would not depend on the IDE.

You are free to type the following yourself

```
/** 
  * Some jsdoc comment 
  */
function someFunction() {
}
```

But ofcourse IDEs can help you with writing such comments. E.g. atom has `docblockr` : https://atom.io/packages/docblockr

I plan to integrate its features into [alm.tools](http://alm.tools) when I am done with the current monaco sprint